# WPF bind background color to a button with a observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a question about WPF Databinding. I want to change the background color of a button with binding values of my ObservableCollection to the button

My Object:

```
public string Position1 { get; set; }
public string Position2 { get; set; }
public string Position3 { get; set; }
public string Position4 { get; set; }
public string Position5 { get; set; }
public string Position6 { get; set; }
public string Position7 { get; set; }
```

I wanted to have these positions inside of a ObservableCollection like below:

```
public ObservableCollection<Positions> Positions { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Positions = new ObservableCollection<Positions>();

            Positions.Add(new Positions
            {
                Position1 = "Red",
                Position2 = "Red",
                Position3 = "Red",
                Position4 = "Gray",
                Position5 = "Green",
                Position6 = "Green",
                Position7 = "Green",
            });
        }
```

Now I am wondering how I can bind these values to the button in XAML?

**I have tried this:**

```
<Button 
        DataContext="Positions[0]"
        Grid.Column="0" 
        Background="{Binding Path=Position1}" 
        x:Name="R1" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Height="100" 
        Margin="5,0,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="109" 
        Click="R1_Click">
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" /> 
    </Button>
```

I have tried to set the datacontext, but I am just very confused in how I can get the values inside of the list in XAML. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: `DataContext="Positions[0]"` is ok for Button, but you need DataContext for Window as well. add `this.DataContext = this;` after all initializtion in constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I added that, but I was wondering if used Binding Path correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is with the Binding the datacontext, since you are binding it as a string, it is not able to understand that its a property in your view model.

Change the DataContext of your button to **"DataContext="{Binding Positions[0]}""**
Then decide which property you want to bind to **Background**.

Change the code to below,

```
          <Button 
          DataContext="{Binding Positions[0]}"
          Grid.Column="0" 
          Background="{Binding Path=Position4}" 
          x:Name="R1" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Height="100" 
          Margin="5,0,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Width="109"
          Click="R1_Click">
              <Rectangle Stroke="Black" />
          </Button>
```

And I hope you are doing the DataContext of your viewmodel to the window in window's constructor.

Hope this helps, if there is some other issue, then don't hesitate to come back :)

Comment: Thanks for the awnser! I am very new to databinding and I don't know how everything works yet. But I am learning and thanks to you I know now how to do this! Thanks very much!

Comment: No worries, enjoy the coding :)

Answer (score -1):

To generate multiple buttons, use an `ItemsControl` with ItemsSource bound to your positions collection.

To actually set the background of each button you need an IConverter class to make this multi-step conversion - first from `string` to `Color` (`ColorConverter.ConvertFromString()`) and then to a `SolidColorBrush` using this color value.

Comment: not really. binding Background to color string works out-of-box. provided that Binding is correct

Comment: I am not generating the buttons, but as ASh said, I don't think it is nessecary. I just wondered if my way of binding is correct and how I can get the values from my ObservableCollection into the background property within WPF